# AWS EC2 : How can i whitelist some ip using command line?

Tags: amazon-ec2

is there any possibility to whitelist some of IP using ssh access in AWS EC2?

Please share anyone have any details?

Comment: Please try executing
"firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-source=192.168.100.0/24"

Comment: What do you mean by "whitelist some of IP using ssh access"? What are you wanting to do? Please edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)?

> A security group acts as a virtual firewall for your instance to control inbound and outbound traffic. When you launch an instance in a VPC, you can assign up to five security groups to the instance. Security groups act at the instance level, not the subnet level. Therefore, each instance in a subnet in your VPC can be assigned to a different set of security groups. If you don't specify a particular group at launch time, the instance is automatically assigned to the default security group for the VPC.
>
> For each security group, you add rules that control the inbound traffic to instances, and a separate set of rules that control the outbound traffic. This section describes the basic things that you need to know about security groups for your VPC and their rules.
>
> You might set up network ACLs with rules similar to your security groups in order to add an additional layer of security to your VPC. For more information about the differences between security groups and network ACLs, see Comparison of Security Groups and Network ACLs.

Comment: Yes but I need to go through Command using SSH because I only have that access.